# Rails error with :has_many :through connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :posts_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts_tags
  has_many :posts, :through => :posts_tags  
end
class PostsTags < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :posts
  belongs_to :tags
end
```

when I want to get post tags:

```
 <% @posts = Post.all %>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
       <% if post.tags.count != 0 %>
          <div class="post-tags">
          <% post.tags.each do |tag| %>
             <span><%= tag.name%></span>
          <%end%>
          </div>    
       <%end%>
    <% end %>
```

I get the error `uninitialized constant Post::PostsTag` 
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the ActiveRecord docs:

> Choosing which way to build a many-to-many relationship is not always simple. If you need to work with the relationship model as its own entity, use has_many :through. Use has_and_belongs_to_many when working with legacy schemas or when you never work directly with the relationship itself.

Since it appears you're only using the `PostsTags` class for the join, you should consider switching to `has_and_belongs_to_many`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags       # foreign keys in the join table
end
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts    # foreign keys in the join table
end
```

You should already have a `posts_tags` table with `post_id` and `tag_id` columns from your `PostsTags` class. If not, then you'll need to create one. Unless you specify a custom name for the join table when you declare the relationship, the table **must** be named `posts_tags`. A possible migration could look like:

```
class CreatePostsTagsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change 
    create_table :posts_tags, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :tag_id
    end
  end
end
```

You should then delete the `app/models/posts_tags.rb` file, since with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, "[t]he join table should not have a primary key or a model associated with it." - ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods

The [documentation for this method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) provides quite of further information on naming the join table and optimizing performance.

Answer (score 1):

The names you pass to `belongs_to` should be singular:

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :tag
```

**Edit**

Also, the model should be named `PostsTag`. ActiveRecord expects all the model names to be singular and to match the table name in plural. Make sure that your table name is 'posts_tags'.

Answer (score 1):

You have a many-to-many relationship and you should read [A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

What you have there is not very difficult but does require some study. As a simple rule: if you are going to use the association (e.g. you want to store a description to PostTag) then use the following code. If not: use `has_and_belongs_to_many` which was already covered in the previous posts. Below a code, with migration, models and view:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :post_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_tags  
end

class PostTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

And your migration should look something like this:

```
class CreateTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :tags do |t|
      # some other attributes here

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :posts do |t|
      # some other attributes here

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :post_tags do |t|
      # some other attributes here
      t.references :post
      t.references :tag

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :tags
    drop_table :posts
    drop_table :post_tags
  end
end
```

And your view should look like this:

```
<% @posts = Post.all %>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
       <% if post.tags.any? %>
          <div class="post-tags">
          <% post.tags.each do |tag| %>
             <span><%= tag.name %></span>
          <%end%>
          </div>    
       <%end%>
    <% end %>
```